# Exporting sld with pyQgis

Tags: python, qgis, sld, pyqgis

Is there a way to export the style of a layer thanks to pyqgis in a sld file? 
I didn't find it in the documentation. I am in a 3.x version of Qgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QgsMapLayer::saveSldStyle](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a1b53c553f87aab1bdf694878cc675446) to export layer style as SLD.

```
layer = iface.addVectorLayer('C:/example.shp', 'mylayer', 'ogr')
layer.saveSldStyle('C:/Styles/SLD/layer_style.sld')
```